# I have this sorted array where i want to add value of position based on the points. If points are same position will be same

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, logic

I am getting the wrong result i have dry run it several times and i am not sure where am i lagging. I have first sorted this array and now i want to create an array from this array which will have the position property in it. That will have the user position based on the points of the user.

```js
var ranking_dayArr = [ { "key": "5K5NODEywoYj2wztGZQfkiZui0I2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "bIluKNDpcuVvG2cIOILVNIm3wd03", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "ix7DniFJKsdEQ4oDvs0AQPMkTf82", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "b79GsKX9weN5lZOt0RWHoS6lP002", "points_neg":-3 }, { "key": "qnGZ7N5OLldg553fA5qVwQIMfa83", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "w4685dkjS4RAr6YFzVrV4gVrF603", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "wY1aixbDcTTimzLLPYsOsjD5GnO2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "Ga71YJ861QVixQ0AugqfVfAcDqw1", "points_neg": -3 }, {"key": "gI9VIXQEqlUJWChZ20zS92FAtkl1", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "Uez7dbef9QciikxVtffEGg3ynYx2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "SERnmqrduSejqSgDzvILJAZ0cKu1", "points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "SPSqJcCdKPhmDqv2QyB66ahLkrr2", "points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "rrKtq0KOCGeCIDAkWHBZUxsx5zF2","points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "4vaF6BVxoDeaKBsDqFb6yGnbhOi2", "points_neg": 0 } ];
var positions = [], position= 1;
for(var i = 0 ; i < ranking_dayArr.length ; i++){
  // console.log(ranking_dayArr[i]);
  // console.log(ranking_dayArr[i].key);
  if(i === 0){
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:(position * -1)}
    });
    position = position + 1; 
  }else if(ranking_dayArr[i-1].points_neg === ranking_dayArr[i].points_neg){
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:(position * -1)}
    });
  }else{
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:(position * -1)}
    })
    position = position + 1;   
  }
} 
console.log(ranking_dayArr);
console.log(positions);
```

please run this code and help me out i need to add position based on user the points of user if 2 users have same points then they would have same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was fine, you just had to comment `position = position + 1;` inside the first `if` condition.

```js
var ranking_dayArr = [ { "key": "5K5NODEywoYj2wztGZQfkiZui0I2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "bIluKNDpcuVvG2cIOILVNIm3wd03", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "ix7DniFJKsdEQ4oDvs0AQPMkTf82", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "b79GsKX9weN5lZOt0RWHoS6lP002", "points_neg":-3 }, { "key": "qnGZ7N5OLldg553fA5qVwQIMfa83", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "w4685dkjS4RAr6YFzVrV4gVrF603", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "wY1aixbDcTTimzLLPYsOsjD5GnO2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "Ga71YJ861QVixQ0AugqfVfAcDqw1", "points_neg": -3 }, {"key": "gI9VIXQEqlUJWChZ20zS92FAtkl1", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "Uez7dbef9QciikxVtffEGg3ynYx2", "points_neg": -3 }, { "key": "SERnmqrduSejqSgDzvILJAZ0cKu1", "points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "SPSqJcCdKPhmDqv2QyB66ahLkrr2", "points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "rrKtq0KOCGeCIDAkWHBZUxsx5zF2","points_neg": 0 }, { "key": "4vaF6BVxoDeaKBsDqFb6yGnbhOi2", "points_neg": 0 } ];
var positions = [], position= 1;
for(var i = 0 ; i < ranking_dayArr.length ; i++){
  // console.log(ranking_dayArr[i]);
  // console.log(ranking_dayArr[i].key);
  if(i === 0){
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:ranking_dayArr[i].points_neg}
    });
    //comment this line
    //position = position + 1; 
  }else if(ranking_dayArr[i-1].points_neg === ranking_dayArr[i].points_neg){
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:ranking_dayArr[i].points_neg}
    });
  }else{
    position = position + 1;
    positions.push({
      key:ranking_dayArr[i].key,
      position : {position:position, position_neg:ranking_dayArr[i].points_neg}
    });   
  }
} 
console.log(ranking_dayArr);
console.log(positions);
```

Comment: I am still getting the wrong output if it gives position the value of 1 where points_neg change to 0. It gives value 2 at the next 0.

Comment: Fixed it. `position = position + 1;` moved this line to top of else condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the predecessor of an object in the array and if they have not the same `points_neg` value then increment the rank.

```js
var data = [{ key: "5K5NODEywoYj2wztGZQfkiZui0I2", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "bIluKNDpcuVvG2cIOILVNIm3wd03", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "ix7DniFJKsdEQ4oDvs0AQPMkTf82", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "b79GsKX9weN5lZOt0RWHoS6lP002", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "qnGZ7N5OLldg553fA5qVwQIMfa83", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "w4685dkjS4RAr6YFzVrV4gVrF603", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "wY1aixbDcTTimzLLPYsOsjD5GnO2", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "Ga71YJ861QVixQ0AugqfVfAcDqw1", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "gI9VIXQEqlUJWChZ20zS92FAtkl1", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "Uez7dbef9QciikxVtffEGg3ynYx2", points_neg: -3 }, { key: "SERnmqrduSejqSgDzvILJAZ0cKu1", points_neg: 0 }, { key: "SPSqJcCdKPhmDqv2QyB66ahLkrr2", points_neg: 0 }, { key: "rrKtq0KOCGeCIDAkWHBZUxsx5zF2", points_neg: 0 }, { key: "4vaF6BVxoDeaKBsDqFb6yGnbhOi2", points_neg: 0 }],
    position = 0,
    result = data.map((o, i, a) =>
        Object.assign({}, o, {
           position: o.points_neg === (a[i - 1] || {}).points_neg ? position : ++position
        }));
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```